# How to use old SATA hard drives as home network storage?

Tags: networking, hard-drive

Here is my home network situation.

I have a router with a single usb 3.0 and several old sata I/II/III 2.5 inch hard drives. Is there any device that I can use to put, say, 4 hdd's in an array then connect the array to the router with usb cable? (I know how to mount a single usb device using dd wrt NAS feature via the router. Essentially I am going for a scheme that I can use some hardware for combining the hdd's.)

I also have a C.H.I.P. computer running as a server at home. Its power is pretty low so another possibility maybe to use external power for the hdd array then drive the hdd array using the C.H.I.P. computer. Again, I am not sure what the best hardware setup for that configuration is.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This question may get closed for being too broad and/or off-topic, however, have you considered setting up a server using Linux? I believe there a couple of distros that are intended for use in a NAS.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Yes, C.H.I.P. is running debian as a webserver as of now. My major constraint is the power consumption of the NAS should be low and I do not need it to be on 24 hours a day. I can use it when I plug it in and plug it out if I am done with it.

Comment: There are USB-to-SATA bridge chips, often used in HDD enclosures. I haven't seen one that has several SATA ports, though. Also, the power consumption of the HDDs is not neglegible. If you are looking for low power as the most important criterion, some kind of flash storage or SSD on USB might be better (but more expensive).

Comment: @dirkt Thanks. To drive a spinning disk, I look at the label, I need 5V ouput and it drains 700mA. So each disk's power consumption is about 3-5w. Four in an array should be around 15-20w, if idle that should be even lower. Like what you said, the question is I haven't seen one-usb to-several-sata hardware on the market except the dedicated NAS box.

Comment: I haven't seen one, either. If there's none, you can use 4 USB-to-SATA bridges, and an USB hub.

Comment: Found one [here](http://www.ioi.com.tw/products/proddetail.aspx?CatID=101&HostID=2044&ProdID=1010132) (JBOD = just a bunch of disks), so they do exist.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, but according to this [article](http://www.techradar.com/news/networking/routers-storage/how-to-turn-old-hard-drives-into-a-secure-file-server-1071446), it is "terrible."

Comment: "JBOD" just means a mode to use each disk invididually, as you intended. And of course that's "terrible" from the point of view of RAID ("it provides no appreciable advantage for redundancy, speed or real convenience beyond being able to slap in more drives."). But I thought that's what you wanted. So if you want RAID, do RAID.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Herb. Just setup a Linux server.  Any old machine with sufficient number of SATA ports will do the job.  You will be much better off than trying to get an array created or even plug in the drives in some sort of SATA to USB to Router connection.